# Codeinginter Fatal error: Class CI_Session_files_drive on PHP 7

Tags: xampp, codeigniter-3, php-7

I have mysterious unsolved problem, the error come from PHP 7 (xampp) on windows 7 x64,
but when using PHP 5.6 everything its running well

```
Fatal error: Class CI_Session_files_driver contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (SessionHandlerInterface::close, SessionHandlerInterface::destroy) in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\system\libraries\Session\drivers\Session_files_driver.php on line 49
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Class CI_Session_files_driver contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (SessionHandlerInterface::close, SessionHandlerInterface::destroy)


Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php
```

I have replace new fresh CodeIgniter system and latest C++ Redistributable but error still appears

Comment: which version of codeigniter are you using. there are numerous version 3s. also are you using php 7 or 7.1?

Comment: Look and see if `Session\drivers\Session_files_driver.php` contains the `close` and `destroy` methods... because mine does, and it sounds like yours doesn't